# how to change background color of second span of bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background

In the loop i have 4 wordpress services , I want to change second service background color ,when I apply css background property it is apply on all the services .

my template code

```
<div class="row">   
    <?php

        $i=1;
        $default_arg =array('class' => "index_ser_img img-responsive" );
        $total_services = $current_options['service_list'];
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'rambopro_service','posts_per_page' =>$total_services) ;  
        $service = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( $service->have_posts() )
        {   while ( $service->have_posts() ) : $service->the_post();    
            $link=1;
            $service_icon_image =  get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'service_icon_image', true ); 
            $meta_service_description =  get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'meta_service_description', true );
            if(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'meta_service_link', true ))
            { $meta_service_link = sanitize_text_field( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'meta_service_link', true )) ; }
            else
            {  $link=0; }
            ?>
            <div class="span3 home_service">
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ ?>
                <span class="icon_align_center">
                  <?php if($link==1) { ?>                   
                <a href="<?php echo $meta_service_link;?>" target="<?php if(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'meta_service_target', true )) echo "_blank";  ?>" >
                <?php
                  the_post_thumbnail('',$default_arg);?>
                </a> <?php  } else {  the_post_thumbnail('',$default_arg);  } ?>  </span>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x icon_align_center"> 
                    <?php if($link==1) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $meta_service_link;?>" target="<?php if(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'meta_service_target', true )) echo "_blank";  ?>" > <i class="fa <?php echo $service_icon_image; ?> home_media_icon_1x fa-inverse"></i></a>
                <?php } else { ?> <i class="fa <?php echo $service_icon_image; ?> home_media_icon_1x fa-inverse"></i>
                <?php } ?>
                </span>
                <?php } if($link==1) {?>
                <a href="<?php echo $meta_service_link;?>" target="<?php if(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'meta_service_target', true )) echo "_blank";  ?>" ><h2><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                <?php } else {  echo '<H2>'; echo the_title() ; echo '</h2>' ;   }?> 
                <p><?php echo $meta_service_description; ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php if($i%4==0){  echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>"; } $i++; endwhile;
        } else
        {  for($j=1; $j<=4; $j++) {  ?>
        <div class="span3 home_service">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x icon_align_center">                 
                <i class="fa fa-flag home_media_icon_1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
            <h2><?php _e('Html5 & Css3',''); ?></h2>
            <p><?php _e('Mauris rhoncus pretium porttitor. Cras scelerisque commodo odio. Phasellus dolor enim, faucibus egestas scelerisque hendrerit, aliquet sed lorem.','rambo');?></p>
            <!-- <a class="home_service_btn" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i><?php _e('Read More','rambo');?></a> -->
        </div>
    <?php } 
    } ?>        
</div>
<!-- /Home Service Section -->
```

link 
http://webriti.com/demo/wp/rambo/

Comment: if the order and number of spans is always the same you could use the css n-th child selector to change only the second one: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can do this two ways:

1) Create a class with the background color you need and add it to the second service:

```
.grey{
background-color: #ececec;
}

<div class="span3 home_service grey">
...
</div>
```

2) Or like *ChaoticNadirs* mentioned, use [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to add only a CSS property that targets only the second service:

```
.span3.home_service:nth-child(2) {
background-color: #ececec;
}
```